# How to create a mesh from a ramp image without discontinuities at the edges in the Y direction

Tags: height-map

I created a plane mesh and subdivided the plane by 100. I then applied a Displace modifier with the following image (0 to 1) as the height map. It works except for the edges in the y direction (see mesh below). I'm not trying to create a simple ramp. This is just one tile of a large map. Does anyone know how to generate a mesh from the below image with the discontinuities at the edges?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the Texture panel, change the Mapping>Extension to "Extend" instead of "Repeat". However the top edge still looks a little ragged after I do this...

Comment: If you slightly scale down the UVs in the UV Editor it should work fine but I'm not sure why

Comment: @scurest It works and the edges look smooth.